# How to create an Email file on AWS while sending an Email using "SpecifiedPickupDirectory" as deliverymethod

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, smtp, smtpclient

Currently we have following configurations for email settings in our .NET application in all developer machines (whereas in production environment only we are sending physical emails).

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="\\devfilesrv01\Emails" />
        <network host="localhost" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Now we are in process of retiring our file storage and moving towards AWS S3 as a storage for all files our application is generating.

While we could successfully done most of the transition, the issue is now at email service where the file generation and storage are driven by configurations.

Following is the code which sends an email:

```
internal static void Send(MailMessage message)
{
    using (var client = CreateSmtpClient())
    {
        client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to overwrite this process when the deliveryMethod is "SpecifiedPickupDirectory" so that I can consume AWS S3 APIs to store the generated files at S3 bucket?

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can directly store email to s3 location. If its publicly accessible, then you can replace \devfilesrv01\Emails with s3 details. But if its not public then you might have to first download in temp location and write a code to move that file from temp location to s3 location.